# Laravel 4: Resource controller with prefix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my route.php i have:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'admin'),function(){
     Route::resource('products','AdminProductsController');
});
```

But when I do the `STORE` function which is a POST, it throws a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` but it works well for the all the `GET` function.

The value of my form's `action` is `{{ URL::to('admin/products/store') }}`.

AdminProductsController.php is in `controller/admin` directory.

Please help.

Controller:

```
<?php

class AdminProductsController extends BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return 'Yow';
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $url = URL::to('admin/products/store');

    return<<<qaz
    <form method="post" action="{$url}">
        <input type="hidden" name="hehehe" value="dfsgg" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
qaz;
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    return 'whahaha';
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    return $id;
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    return $id;
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}

}
```

Comment: I think you have a typo there, shouldn't the line be: `Route::resource('products','AdminProductsController');` ?

Comment: Can you share the code in the Controller?  specifically for the `store` action that you mention?

Comment: Please check it again

Comment: can you try updating the `$url` you're setting on the form?  From the docs, I think it should be simply: `$url = URL::to('admin/products');`

Comment: did it work ok for you?

Comment: yes it works but i think it is more formal and make your code understandable if we will use the route name. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is in the Route used in your example.

Try this

```
<form method="post" action="{{ URL::route('admin.products.store') }}">
```

Now you should be good to go!

Advice: get a look at url/actions/named routes in Laravel - may be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers), the `store` action is accessed via the root path of the Controller (in your case `/admin/products`), but is triggered by the `POST` verb, rather than `GET`, which triggers the `index` action.

In other words, if you update the `$url` you're setting as the form's `action` in your `create()` action:

```
public function create()
{
    $url = URL::to('admin/products');

    return<<<qaz
    <form method="post" action="{$url}">
        <input type="hidden" name="hehehe" value="dfsgg" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
qaz;
}
```

And that Should Just Work. :)

Check out the table of `Verb | Path | Action | Route Name` in that link above for more details.  The `path` column shows where you can access the actions.